# Understanding the different versions of Python and how their paths operate

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, pip

This question arises from the fact that I have multiple versions of Python installed, and therefore I believe multiple versions of `pip` as well as multiple places that Python packages could be installed.

For instance, in the command line, typing `Python` and then `tab tab` produces the following output:

```
python             python2.7-32       python3.3m-config  pythonw2-32
python-32          python2.7-config   python3.4          pythonw2.6
python-config      python3            python3.4-32       pythonw2.7
python2            python3-32         python3.4-config   pythonw2.7-32
python2-32         python3-config     python3.4m         pythonw3
python2-config     python3.3          python3.4m-config  pythonw3-32
python2.6          python3.3-32       pythonw            pythonw3.3
python2.6-config   python3.3-config   pythonw-32         pythonw3.3-32
python2.7          python3.3m         pythonw2
```

I have noticed that when running certain versions of `IDLE`, some packages I thought I installed, such as `requests` are not available.

Am I correct that each time I use `pip` to install a package, I should specify which version of `pip` to use (in my case I have `pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.4` installed), and that will only install the package to it's corresponding Python version?

Also, here both plain `python` and `pip` show up as possible commands. The first lines of my `$PATH` are `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/` but `python` defaults to version 2.7 and `pip` defaults to an older version. Why is this? I thought that as soon as my OS finds the command available in the `PATH` it uses that version.

Comment: Instead of attempting to answer the question, I'll offer some advice: Stop what you're doing and go read about virtualenvs: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: `pip` and `python` belong together as well as `pip3` and `python3`. Depending on what version you have installed, `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7` `python`, `python2` and `python2.7` all belong together. The same holds for `pip3`, `python3` and `python3.4`. When you install a new Python version, let's say 3.5, it'll install `python3.5` and update `python3` to use that version.